# How do I use Content-Security-Policy in the options page of a Chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to add a widget to my Chrome extension's options page, but can't seem to get past the error it gives.

**TL;DR:**
CSP (Content-Security-Policy) isn't allowing an external script to load on my options.html page of my Chrome extension. I've tried following MDN documentation and Chrome Extension documentation but can't get it to work unless I copy-paste the external JavaScript file and host it locally, but I'm not sure if this is an acceptable method when it comes to security or when it comes time to publish the extension to Chrome Web Store.

Here's what I've tried doing...

I've added this to the head of my options.html:

```
<meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' https://js.example.com;"
    />
```

But I'm still receiving these 2 errors in my console when running the page:

*Refused to load the script 'https://js.example.com/1.0.0/widget.prod.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.*

*Refused to load the script 'https://js.example.com/1.0.0/widget.prod.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.*

I've tried including the entire external JavaScript source URL in the meta tag like this, but I still get the same 2 error messages.

```
<meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' https://js.example.com/1.0.0/widget.prod.min.js;"
    />
```

I've also tried adding a second content-security-policy like this, but then it fails to load the 'self' JavaScript:

```
<meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="script-src-elem https://js.example.com;"
    />
```

And I've tried adding to the initial Content-Security-Policy meta tag like this, but it also fails to load the 'self' JavaScript:

```
<meta
      http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
      content="script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; script-src-elem https://js.example.com;"
    />
```

I've been reading every MDN documentation related to CSP: script-src but can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I've even started watching YouTube videos and reading random blog articles related to CSP (Content-Security-Policy) but nothing I've tried based on my research has worked.

*I've also reviewed some similar questions asked here on StackOverflow but can't seem to find a solid answer.

One of the recommendations was to add your CSP to the manifest.json, which I did, but the CSP section says you can only use 'self', 'none', 'wasm-unsafe-eval' and local sources. (seems like you can't use external sources unless you're using sandbox?)

So I tried doing this, but received the same errors again (I'm not sure if I coded this correctly though, I couldn't find how to add the "script-src 'self' ..." for "extension_pages", only for "sandbox").

```
 "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "options.html",
    "extension_pages": "allow-scripts; script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval'"
  }
```

One alternative I tried was grabbing the external JavaScript file and copy-pasting it into a local file. This method got the widget loading and functioning as expected, but I'm not sure if this would be a good practice.

Some questions I have with using this method:

- Are there security risks when doing this?
- Will my extension be allowed to be published to Chrome Web Store if I leave it like this?

Comment: Remove the first `extension_pages` (the entire line) and `allow-scripts;`.

Comment: Tried this and am still receiving errors for both 'self' and 'wasm-unsafe-eval'; widget and external fonts aren't loading in.

Comment: You can't load external resources in ManifestV3.